# Limit git shortlog to date range

Tags: git

I was attempting to use `git shortlog` to find the number of commits per author within a directory and given date range. So for example I used

```
git shortlog -ns -- /folder/subfolder --since="1 year ago"
```

This outputs the correct format

```
105  Bob
 71  Alice
 60  Charlie
```

However it seems to be ignoring my `--since` argument. No matter what I enter it lists total commits for the entire git history (I've tried only going back 1 week or 1 day for example, same output). What is the correct way to specify a date range?

`git version 2.28.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:
`git shortlog -ns --since "1 year ago" --`

So I guess the `--since` should be before the `--` separator, not after it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write this for a past time period from today on (day, month, year):

```
git shortlog -ns folder/subfolder --since="4 month ago"
```

And if you want to define the date range with dates, you can make it like this:

```
git shortlog -ns folder/subfolder --since="01 Okt 2020" --before="01 Feb 2021"
```